# How to generically refer to a type that has a static constructor function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, static

I have some generated code (gRPC) that produces various classes each of which have a static constructor function like `static create(): Foo`. Each of these classes has its own static constructor function that explicitly returns itself (A's function returns an `A` object, etc).

I'm trying to create a generic interface that captures this information, at compile time, and then write a generic function to refer to each class, and then pass a handler callback which receives an instance of that class.

```js
// ----- generated code starts -----
class A {
    name = 'AAA';

    static create(): A {
        return new A();
    }
}

class B {
    age = 32;

    static create(): B {
        return new B();
    }
}

class C {
    location = 'New York';

    static create(): C {
        return new C();
    }
}


// ----- generated code ends -----

/**
 * Represents a class that can be constructed by calling a static method
 */
interface StaticallyConstructable<OBJ> {
    create(): OBJ;
}

function registerHandler<CLS extends StaticallyConstructable<CLS>>(ObjClass: CLS, handler: (obj: CLS) => void) {
    const obj = ObjClass.create();
    handler(obj);
}

registerHandler(C, (obj: C) => {
    obj.location
});
```

The `registerHandler` function itself compiles fine, but when I call it with an actual class like `C` and a handler that receives a `C`, I get the following error:

```
Property 'location' is missing in type 'StaticallyConstructable<C>' but required in type 'C'.
```

Edit: [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsE9QQwVwC4HsDmBTAdmgTjBaATUAYyQLQChiAbGAZztAEFQBvC0T0DGcNUALygA5EzHCA3BQ5c6CPAEtiJbGjxoAFAEoAXMzYyuXVQjjYM3NAHdm2qUYC%20FJ1VoNQAIQNGY6QaABmACYpQ1A5RWViVXVtPS92IyMTMwssGw87MKcXGnpGAGFvLmokYkUkCyFhADlrUABNJGwAa0lpIwiEJRU1fDjQIsSkzhTzSxsCrMdnaRAIaAAHbCQAKzRiBApgACodjh3QACU0ZbQ6TARGGBI3RgQACzwSGAsAI35SDDlsOE3CUBvaDlajUBQYFCwcLybrKPiPMgHYAUcH4bAAMxgxH4AGUYUoYKDIAVKj8-vI3tQ0AAeADyHgAUgA%20YqcaJ9TS6UD0hlSFzouAYTYKSqgVQoBRyHAACVeBCp2GpBQAMjjQGgAB74DAERh4yKE6jE0kIX6bGCUmkqnFMpkaWlvVYFO56a0AGlATx1Cr0GiQjtdqq0ghZADckAoCMHhmyTaB-at-A6nXcAHTs2JaexcL3ynB%20x1Z2YUcWStGy735goegurV3BgQsmPxx2p0rlbqVZxFoA)

Comment: How about https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XRAe2GALgSwwDtoBeaAcgDkBTAd2gE0MAnAa3IG4kU0Idc8waMGbVc1ABQBKAFxxEPNGlE4Ars2KE6caVyUBfJIaQB6E9AC2AT2gAHZhgBW1YDlMAqdynfQAStXtqCGpCHBgwYXAoaBwAC1xhMGIAI2phIj5mVVdqABNoZJtsEBA8QgBzaAi+ASELajiMXO8TJDKcamYAMzBgNIBlfnxikCtYDJws1zBkkGoAHgB5ACEAKQA+BSURMQ7pORXVrmMu1UJXAmJRcrw+ToAJJNy55nnYABl+9YlF5MdYKIQOSDWpgEpjCZTfizBYfL4AGmg8UIz06cgkGD+cjhUlImwAbhg8LlcchthNoJjHKRoL9-oCAHQ7cS6RRIp4vDF-KTHbjXW4dZiPFGc2CIrmObG4kibMloKkMzDYfBEIw8pBAA

Comment: wow, that actually works! not sure why I didn't think of that. Feel free to post it as a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLS` should represent the instance type, so the `ObjClass` should be of type `StaticallyConstructable<CLS>`

```
function registerHandler<CLS>(ObjClass: StaticallyConstructable<CLS>, handler: (obj: CLS) => void) {
    const obj = ObjClass.create();
    handler(obj);
}

registerHandler(C, (obj: C) => {
    obj.location
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDC0G8BQ1XRAe2GALgSwwDtoBeaAcgDkBTAd2gE0MAnAa3IG4kU0Idc8waMGbVc1ABQBKAFxxEPNGlE4Ars2KE6caVyUBfJIaQB6E9AC2AT2gAHZhgBW1YDlMAqdynfQAStXtqCGpCHBgwYXAoaBwAC1xhMGIAI2phIj5mVVdqABNoZJtsEBA8QgBzaAi+ASELajiMXO8TJDKcamYAMzBgNIBlfnxikCtYDJws1zBkkGoAHgB5ACEAKQA+BSURMQ7pORXVrmMu1UJXAmJRcrw+ToAJJNy55nnYABl+9YlF5MdYKIQOSDWpgEpjCZTfizBYfL4AGmg8UIz06cgkGD+cjhUlImwAbhg8LlcchthNoJjHKRoL9-oCAHQ7cS6RRIp4vDF-KTHbjXW4dZiPFGc2CIrmObG4kibMloKkMzDYfBEIw8pBAA)